# Google Sheet Formulas

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a spreadsheet setup where I have a column with some dates in each month. I have to count the number of dates that occur in the month of Jan, Feb, etc.

The column looks like below:

```
1/24/2019
2/7/2019
3/14/2019
6/3/2019
6/6/2019
6/6/2019
6/10/2019
6/13/2019
6/13/2019
6/13/2019
6/17/2019
6/24/2019
7/10/2019
7/10/2019
7/25/2019
8/12/2019
8/15/2019
8/15/2019
8/26/2019
8/12/2019
8/26/2019
8/26/2019
8/26/2019
8/12/2019
9/6/2019
9/6/2019
9/9/2019
10/1/2019
9/13/2019
9/16/2019
9/19/2019
9/24/2019
```

I tried using the formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT('LACHC Response Tracker'--(DAY($G1:$G)=H35))
```

This did not work. Can someone please recommend me how to do this. Response tracker is another spreadsheet where I have that column. I have to use the calculated value on another sheet created on another tab.

Comment: Please provide some more clarity. Like what exactly is the column name here, and what exactly is the column name in the other sheet?

Comment: LACHC Response tracker is google spreadsheet having column G. G is labelled as Date and has the dates explained above. I have another tab created called "Production tracker" where the value calculated is to be stored in cell H35. If 2 dates are there for January in col G, then H35 will store 2

Comment: ? anyone can help me with this please

Answer (score 1):

make sure your column contains true dates and use this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A1:A, TEXT(A1:A, "mmm")}, 
 "select Col2,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col2 
  label count(Col1)''", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Since the date column is in another sheet. Let’s call it sheet 2. Results have to be stored in a cell called h35 on sheet3. How would you frame this formula then?

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Sheet2!A1:A, TEXT(Sheet2!A1:A, "mmm")}, 
 "select Col2,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col2 
  order by count(Col1) desc
  label count(Col1)''", 0))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Gj5U.png

Comment: Where are you storing the value on sheet3 h35

Comment: But ur using the same sheet to store your counts. What if the cell is in another spreadsheet

Comment: if it's in another sheet/tab use: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Sheet2!A1:A, TEXT(Sheet2!A1:A, "mmm")}, "select Col2,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 order by count(Col1) desc label count(Col1)''", 0))`

Comment: if it's in another spreadsheet/file use: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("ID_or_URL", Sheet2!A1:A), TEXT(IMPORTRANGE("ID_or_URL", Sheet2!A1:A), "mmm")}, "select Col2,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 order by count(Col1) desc label count(Col1)''", 0))`

Comment: =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({LACHC Response Tracker!G1:G, TEXT(LACHC Response Tracker!G1:G, "mmm")}, "select H35,count(G) where G is not null group by H35 order by count(G) desc label count(G)''", 0)) .  This did not work

Comment: use this: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({'LACHC Response Tracker'!G1:G, TEXT('LACHC Response Tracker'!G1:G, "mmm")}, "select Col2,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 order by count(Col1) desc label count(Col1)''", 0))`

Comment: The counts I am getting is correct but the issue is the format I am getting. LACHC has another column called enrollment. That column contains yes, no, pending. The format I have on the sheet where I am trying to get these values is: 1) Month 2)Yes 3) No 4)Pending. How would I change this query such that it populates in this format. Also what does the zero stand for?

Comment: the 0 is for "no header rows"

Comment: =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({'T.H.E Response Tracker'!G1:G, TEXT('T.H.E Response Tracker'!G1:G, "mmm")}, "select Col2,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 order by count(Col1) desc label count(Col1)''", 0)) This is the statement i used. However there is another column which tracks the enrollment for the month using yes, no, pending. How would the query look to go granular on those areas? Example if two dates in january had yes, my yes column would show 2. If there were three dates out of which two were yes and one was no, then yes would have 2 and no would have 1

Comment: Also the code you gave me sorts the months based off the values. I dont need to do that. I have the months from Jan to Dec. I need the value to populate if it exists for the month. So the table to collect values is laid out as 1) Month 2)yes 3)No 4)Pending 5)Grand Total

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output?